# Unregistering nested property deletes the whole object

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-empties-values-react-hook-form-r9s49?file=/src/App.js) of my react-hook-form demo.

You'll notice all my fields are virtual, there is no input component for them:

```
const form = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    groups: {}
  }
});
```

So you see my default values start at: `{ groups: {} }`.

I am able to successfully add a group like this:

```
form.register(`groups.${groupId}`);
form.setValue(`groups.${groupId}`, { name: "foo" });
```

Doing this is good, I expect this behavior, it makes my values now: `{ groups: { [groupId]: { name: 'foo' } }`

However when I try to delete with:

```
form.unregister(`groups.${groupId}`)
```

It deletes the entire `groups` object. My values unexpectedly is now `{}`. I was expecting it to be `{ groups: {} }`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RHF will remove the whole object if you `unregister` the last property inside it:

```
// {
//   groups: {
//     Group1: { ... },
//     Group2: { ... },
//   }
// }


form.unregister(`groups.Group2`);
// {
//   groups: {
//     Group1: { ... },
//   }
// }

form.unregister(`groups.Group1`);
// {}
```

I had a look at the `unregister` method and there are no [options](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/unregister/#:%7E:text=%7B%20firstName%3A%20%27%27%20%7D-,Options,-Name) to retain the object shape if it's empty inside. A workaround is simply create a dummy field:

```
const form = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    groups: {
      _: true
    }
  }
});
```

And make it un-unregisterable:

```
Object.entries(groups)
  .filter((g) => g[0] !== "_")
  .map(([groupId, group]) => (
    <div key={groupId}>
      <h4>Group ID: {groupId}</h4>
      <DeleteGroupButton groupId={groupId} />
    </div>
  ));
```